# why docker-compose generate container and docker run generate container have difference?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

i have a docker image install linux command awk.
when i use `docker run -it --name test1 -d opensshjdk:v20230315` it generate a container.
and then use `docker exec -ti test1 bash` go into container.
now i can use awk.
`root@1c92c111ba:/# awk` 
but, if use docker-compose like that:
`docker-compose -f docker-compose-back.yml up -d`

docker-compose-back.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  workspace-svc-8999:
    image: "workspace-svc-8999:latest"
    restart: "no"
    build: server-8999
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /root/workspace-docker-compose/server-8999:/var/lib/vdi/workspace-server/
      - /root/workspace-docker-compose/log:/var/log/vdi/workspace-server/
      - /etc/rabbitmq/client/:/etc/rabbitmq/client/
      - /etc/rabbitmq/trustStore:/etc/rabbitmq/trustStore
      - /etc/:/etc/
      - /vms/:/vms/
    ports:
      - 8999:8999
      - 7001:7001
    container_name: workspace-svc-8999
    network_mode: "host"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 50m
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM opensshjdk:v20230315

VOLUME /tmp
ADD workspace-server.jar workspace-server.jar
ADD arthas-packaging-3.3.3-bin arthas-packaging-3.3.3-bin
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh/
ADD id_rsa  id_rsa
RUN cp id_rsa /root/.ssh/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/vdi/workspace-server
ADD qcow2vhd.sh qcow2vhd.sh
RUN cp qcow2vhd.sh /var/log/vdi/workspace-server/


ENTRYPOINT java -jar -server -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/vdi/workspace-server/heapDump -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/vdi/workspace-server/ws-error-%p.log -Xloggc:/var/log/vdi/workspace-server/ws-gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=50m -Duser.country=CN -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7001  -Duser.language=zh -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true /workspace-server.jar --server.port=8999 --spring.profiles.active=prod

EXPOSE 8999
EXPOSE 7001
```

then use `docker exec -ti workspace-svc-8999 bash`
it print out  `bash-5.0#`  if enter awk. it display `bash: awk command not found.`
but i can found `awk` use command `find / -name awk`.
Please help me. Thanks a lot.

i want use linux command awk in docker-compose container.

Comment: What do you need to do, with awk, in a debugging shell, that you don't want to do in the Java code that's the main container process?  The bind mount over all of the container's `/etc` is likely to cause problems, for example specifying shared-library paths in an `/etc/ld.so.conf` that may not exist in the container.  (Can you delete _all_ of the `volumes:`?)

Comment: Thank you ! David. You are right.  i try to mount `/etc` in the docker. it is a wrong decision. the host infect the docker container command. Very Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

The image you are using in your `docker-compose` file is different from the one you are targeting with your `docker run`